# Is there any way to delete the windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Specifically, I want it gone. I am using parallels to run windows 7 and I have several ways to get to applications and simply do not need it on the desktop. I know it can be auto-hidden, but I prefer it gone.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to delete the windows
>   7 taskbar?

You can't delete the taskbar but you can eliminate it.

> Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator is a great
>   utility which will simply and
>   efficiently remove the taskbar from
>   Windows XP or Vista.
>
> With just the click of a button or a
>   hotkey, the taskbar is disabled from
>   any side of the screen, providing the
>   freedom to use any dock application,
>   increase computer security, or allow
>   all sorts of Windows customizations.
>   The taskbar can be toggled on and off
>   in real-time, providing the
>   flexibility to quickly view the
>   taskbar to perform an action.
>
> The application interface is simple
>   and easy to understand, allowing it to
>   be used by even the most novice of
>   users. Simply press and hold
>   Control+Alt+T to bring up the
>   Preferences window, from which all
>   options can be adjusted. Press and
>   hold Alt + T to immediately show or
>   hide the taskbar directly.

[image]

Supported Operating Systems:

Windows 98
Windows 2000
Windows XP
Windows Vista
**Windows 7 Beta & Release Candidate**

**[Download](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator)**

*Aviassin Taskbar Eliminator is freeware and portable.*

when you click 'Hide Taskbar' it will disappear but the start orb remains visible, however, if you set the the taskbar to 'Auto Hide' before eliminating the taskbar, it works like a charm. the start orb will not appear if you hit the bottom of the screen, ONLY if you press the windows key.

[image]

... and then use **[VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html)** to toggle conveniently between open applications and folders.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell replacement such as the ones listed below:

- [Litestep](http://www.litestep.net/)
- [SharpEShell](http://www.sharpe-shell.org/news.php)
- [bblean](http://bb4win.sourceforge.net/bblean/)

These programs are called **shell replacements** because they replace the default Windows shell, in this case, the taskbar.